# Redundant-looking module and class names

Tags: python

Need some advice on the naming on python when creating packages with classes.

I am trying to create some reusable helper package for internal use, say:

```
from local_helper import email
from local_helper.db import mssql
from local_helper.db import orcale
```

With folder structure:

```
local_helper\
|-- __init__.py
|-- email.py
+-- db\
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- mssql.py
    |-- orcale.py
```

But as I am implementing the logic as a class so it turn out become:

```
from local_helper.email import Email
from local_helper.db.mssql import Mssql
from local_helper.db.orcale import Orcale
```

which look very redundant to me.

I can put all my code into `__init__.py` but it don't look like a good idea as I may adding many stuff into the helper package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can import it to `__init__`

```
# db/__init__.py
from .mssql import Mssql
```

And now, you can do it shorter

```
from db import Mssql
```

Comment: Thanks, this look great, let's me give it a try